# Get data from PHP file using AJAX when it is only single line result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I really thought I would figure this one out but I am stuck.
I only want to get one single result from this PHP file, so I believe it is unescessary to use an array then?

However, I've tried console.log(result) multiple times but I am only recieving "null".

What am I doing wrong?

AJAX:

```
 $.ajax({
            url: "includes/getwinner.php", 
            success: (function (result) {
                 console.log(result);
               })
             })
```

PHP

```
include("../steamauth/db.php");

$result=mysqli_query($db, "select low_winner from pots");
$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

echo $row['low_winner'];
```

Comment: Is it working when you directly call your php Script?

Comment: The PHP? I am fetching data from the database. Printing $row['low_winner'] using echo. The PHP file is the getwinner.php

Comment: Oh, I will check

Comment: Yes it does....

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: What are the outputs in the console when the ajax call is made and when you directly run the php script?

Comment: This is the output ` Unexpected token R in JSON`

Comment: I'm guessing the URL in your AJAX call is not the right path. The result being 'null' is not from the PHP file.

Comment: What happens if you simply place `echo 123;exit;` at the top of the script, before everything else?

Comment: Are you specifing any `dataType` in your AJAX call?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if ($result = mysqli_query($db, "select low_winner from pots")) {

    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo $row["Name"];
    }

    /* free result set */
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
```

Use the `mysqli_free_result` function correctly, docs [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php).